# Disabling shift-Windows key in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Windows 7 set those Windows+Shift keys for moving windows to the other screens:

<kbd>[image: Windows logo] (Win)</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→ (Right Arrow)</kbd>
or <kbd>[image: Windows logo] (Win)</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd>
moves the window to the other side of the dual monitor setup.

How can I disable this? It conflicts with Emacs/org mode's keys, and I find it annoying.

Comment: I'm confused as to what shortcut you mean.  Windows+Shift doesn't do anything for me in Win7...

Comment: @Shinrai : They are Windows-Shift-Left/Right.

Comment: Oh, that's nice to know actually, thanks.  Sorry I can't help at all with turning it off though.

Comment: It may be part of the video card driver - Intel cards have the most annoying ability to flip the display upside down just by accidentally pressing control and downarrow.

Comment: Just a small note that 3rd party applications should ***not*** rely on Windows logo key. Complain at Emacs/org to get an alternative in Emacs. This way you will also help other Emacs users.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas it has nothing to do with Intel drivers (which uses Ctrl+Alt+Arrow to rotate screens). This is a Windows built-in feature

Answer (score 0):

This site has a couple options you can try: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5937-windows-key-shortcuts-enable-disable.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to change keybindings (and much more), so that the shortcuts you mention have no effect.

The AutoHotkey script in order to disable the mentioned shortcuts would be something like:

```
#+Left::Return
#+Right::Return
```

`#` Stands for the <kbd>[image: Windows logo] (Win)</kbd>
`+` Stands for <kbd>Shift</kbd>
`Left/Right` stands for the <kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd>, <kbd>→ (Right Arrow)</kbd>, respectively.

You just have to install AutoHotkey, create `*.ahk` (plain text) file with the script above and add it to your `Startup` folder.